# have anyone tried to install prism template pack in Xamarin studio on Mac?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have tried to install same, but no success. Getting below error.

Could not get information from repository: http://addins.monodevelop.com/Alpha/Mac/6.1.5/main.mrep.

Xamarin studio Version (On Mac )
Version: 6.1.5 (Build 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try manually downloading the .mpack file and add it. You can grab the file from here: http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/226

Once you have the .mpack downloaded, follow these steps to install it from Xamarin Studio.

- Go to the Xamarin Studio -> Add-ins menu
- Click the "Install from file..." button on the lower left.
- Select the .mpack file you downloaded
- Press "Open" to select it

Comment: I was searching for this file location, but didn't came to stack :-(. after getting the link I came here to post & it is already here :-)

Answer (score 0):

I installed it using the method therealjohn outlined. However, the XS version is not as good as the Visual Studio one (Windows version). In XS, when you create a new PrismContentPage, it only adds the page and wires it up for you. On Windows, it creates the page, wires it up for you, and creates the associated ViewModel in the correct location with the correct base class. In some cases it might register your view and viewmodels with your DI container automatically.