# Prism template pack for Visual Studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, visual-studio-mac, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I've searched all over the internet to no avail. Is there a visual studio Prism template pack for Visual Studio v7.0.1 for Mac? 
The [closest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901074/1670574) I've seen to this template is for Xamarin Studio which is not compatible with the new Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not currently a template pack available for VS4Mac. It is something that is being discussed, and will likely get visited once we get the v7.0 preview released. You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Extensibility/issues/1).

While it's not exactly something that's currently integrated with VS or VS4Mac you can use the dotnet templates available [here](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism-Templates). They do work cross platform, currently from the dotnet cli, but the VS team is working on integration for all of the templates for both VS2017 and VS4Mac.

Comment: Thanks. The git templates may come in handy, for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can now install the Templates on VS4Mac. Go to `Visual Studio` => `Extensions`, select the `Gallery` tab, click the `Repository` drop-down, and select `Manage Repositories` and add https://prism.azureedge.net/main.mrep

Then on the search bar, you can look up for prism and install the template.